Pubsub retention period effect on cost
Is there any effect on cost if we set the retention period to 7 days instead of say 2 or 3 days in GCP pubsub?
Let's say I keep it 7 days but whatever backlog I have gets cleared within a day itself. Then does it make a difference what I choose in the subscription configuration?

As of today (June 4, 2024), Pub/Sub does not charge for the storage of a subscription's unacknowledged messages.
However, starting from June 30, 2024, Pub/Sub will start charging for the storage of subscription unacknowledged messages which are not acked within 24 hours. This change is documented in the Pub/Sub documentation.
In your scenario, setting the subscription message retention period to 7 days instead of 2-3 days would not incur any charges, because you are clearing your backlog within a day. However, if something unusual happens and your subscribers are not able to process a message within a day, your message would be kept for up to 7 days instead of 2-3 days. This would increase the duration of time you have to reprocess the message, but could also increase your storage costs while the message remains unacked.
Note that the above only applies to subscription unacked message retention duration.
A topic message retention duration of 7 days would incur more storage costs than a duration of 2-3 days, because messages are kept for 7 days regardless of whether they are acked. This makes them available for replay anytime in that 7-day window.
Similarly, if you enable the retain acknowledged messages setting on your subscription, setting a subscription message retention duration of 7 days would incur more storage costs than a duration of 2-3 days, because the acknowledged messages will be kept for 7 days.
